# Write out all the elements of $K$ and check that a product is in $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let us abbreviate $0 = [0]$ and $1 = [1]$ in $\mathbb Z_5.$ Let $G = GL_2(\mathbb Z_5).$ 
>   (a) Let $$H=\{\begin{bmatrix}
> x & 0 \\
> 0 & y
> \end{bmatrix}, \text{ where } x,y \in \mathbb Z_5^{\times}\}.$$ 
>   Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and find its order. 
>   (b) Let $K = \langle \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\rangle.$ Write out all the elements of $K$ and show that $K$ is isomorphic to $Z_m$ for some $m.$ 
>  
>   (c) If $A \in H$, carefully check that $A \begin{bmatrix} 
> 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix} A^{-1} \in K$.

**My attempt:** 
a) Let $H' = \begin{bmatrix}
x' & 0 \\
0 & y' \end{bmatrix}, \text{ where } x',y' \in \mathbb Z_5^{\times},$ then $$HH' = \begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x' & 0 \\
0 & y' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
xx' & 0 \\
0 & yy' \end{bmatrix} \in H,$$ since $\mathbb Z_5^{\times}$ is a group, and therefore, $xx', yy' \in \mathbb Z_5^{\times}.$ Thus, $H$ is closed under matrix multiplication. 
$ I = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in H,$ so $H$ has an identity. 
$$H^{-1} = \frac{1}{xy}\begin{bmatrix}
y & 0 \\
0 & x \end{bmatrix}=\pm \begin{bmatrix}
y & 0 \\
0 & x \end{bmatrix}$$ (since $H$ is in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_5).$ Hence $H^{-1}$ is in $H$. Thus, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. 
b) Note that $K^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, n \in \mathbb Z_5,$ so $$K=\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \}.$$ Since the order of $K$ is $5$, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5.$
c) $A = \begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & y \end{bmatrix},$ then $$A = A\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & y \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & y \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \pm \begin{bmatrix}
x & x \\
0 & y \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y & 0 \\
0 & x \end{bmatrix}= \pm \begin{bmatrix}
1 & xx \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

How is my proof for parts (a) and (b)? I have a feeling that I messed up somewhere, because I don't know how to show that the last matrix is in $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, up to the calculation of the inverse matrix. Note that the inverse of a matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix}$ is given by

$$A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} x^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & y^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$$

and this is an element of $H$ since $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. For (c), it now follows that

$$A \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} A^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix} x & x \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & y^{-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & xy^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in K.$$